Jenkins prevent a parent job from being executed when child job is running
This should be an easy one for a jenkins expert:
I have a parent JOB A executing another pipeline script. Once that one is finished, it triggers a child JOB B, also executing a pipeline.
Like this:
Job A
-> executes pipeline groovy script with several steps
once finished it should trigger
Job B
-> executes pipeline groovy script with several steps
I realized that the parent job can be started even if the child B and its pipeline scipt is still running. How can I prevent this?
The JOB A triggers the child job B with this in the child job-groovy script:
    triggers {
        upstream('Job A')
    }

BTW: I have in the actual executed pipeline scripts this:
pipeline {
...
    options {
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
        timeout(time: 22, unit: 'HOURS')
    }
...
}

However, this has no effect.

Not clear on what you are trying to prevent? Suppose Job B is not running, you start Job A, and then someone triggers Job B manually? If two jobs should be executed strictly sequentially with no overlap then maybe they belong together, as in one job?

They don't belong together as the first job builds an instance, on which the second job builds some test. Sometimes, you want only the first job (but not when the second job is running). Furthermore, 1 is running on linux, and the other on a windows machine. First job is normally triggered via SCM poll. But manual intervention can happen, which can cause problems.

What’s the issue with building an instance when a different instance is running tests? Besides, pipelines can run on multiple machines.

Is it a problem for your case if the parent jobs JOB-A starts and stays in pipeline or do you want to not execute at all ??  Both have different uses. The second one would skip polling and any new changes during the duration of the blocking period and the first one will basically increase your pending jobs in your queue.

@Iterokun The problem is, that Job A can run independently, Job B only if Job a runs through. So, I can not let it run on differnet machines in parallel

@SiddharthKaul No problem if Job B is running, Job A can be staying in the pipeline until Job B is finished. But this is exactly what is not working. The scenario is this: Job A builds an application on a linux server, Job B runs tests on it in windows.

I wasn't suggesting running them in parallel. It sounds like either they are two sequential stages (the stage for Job B can be conditionally skipped) or Job A needs to trigger Job B with some parameters that specify which artifact to test.

@Iterokun I had it originally as you suggested, as one job. But then it took the flexibility to run each separately. And anyway, I had the described scenario in an older jenkins version, just without pipeline scripts. Simply: Job A trigger Job B after finished and Job A goes in a Queue should Job still running.

Btw, thanki you for all your imput.

@Jonas Build blocker is your friend here.  https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-blocker-plugin/ This will keep your job in the pipeline queue but will only execute once job b finishes.
